# string error when executing sql command

Tags: php, sql, forms

i want to select a database from a list of databases and work with it but I get error saying database doesn't exist.
My code is:
    SELECT DATABASE TO WORK WITH

```
<form action = "createtable.php" method = "post">
    <?php
    $query = "SHOW DATABASES";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
    if(!$result) { echo mysql_error(); var_dump($result);
        var_dump($connect); var_dump($query); }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<input type = "radio" name = "db" value =' . $row[0] . '/>' . $row[0] . "<br>";
    }
    ?>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" />
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo 'submit done';
    $db = $_POST['db'];
    $query = "USE $db";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
    if(!$result) {
        echo 'no' . mysql_error();
        var_dump($db);
    }
}
```

the var_dump gives me 
     string 'imt/' (length=4)
 so I know that's the error. The question now is how can I escape this?

Comment: just remove the slash, if your database is `imt` and if it's not absolutely incorrect output

Comment: the slash is definitely tthe problem. but isn't removing it a bad practice?

Comment: it is, but why on earth your query returns a slashe appended string after the DB? If I try your approach I recieve `array (size=2)
  0 => string 'information_schema' (length=18)
  'Database' => string 'information_schema' (length=18)`

Comment: OK, I get it. `value =' . $row[0] . '/>'` this will evaluate into `value=string/> which will interprete the value as `string/`. You should double quote it like `value="string"/>`

Comment: double quote the string...got it

Comment: just did that and it didn't work. it sends $row['0'] as the string value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it returns no wrong results, but it seems it causes the fact that I have enclosed the PHP tag and write the radio button without any mess with PHP in it. So I get deep into your quotation and I saw this

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{echo '<input type = "radio" name = "db" value =' . $row[0] . '/>' . $row[0] . "<br>";}
?>
```

Which will result into

```
<input type = "radio" name = "db" value = imt/>
```

So the value will become `imt/`.

You should enclose it with quotes `value ="' . $row[0] . '"/>`, or, better

DO NOT mess PHP and HTML :)

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):?>
    <input type = "radio" name = "db" value = "<?=$row[0];?>"/> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: this...is...new to me.

Comment: @brown.cn well :) it should be common sense that you can separate HTML and PHP as they are independent languages

Comment: yeah but you added a query tag without a specification...why?

Comment: @brown.cn sorry, I did not understand, could you elaborate

Comment: the <? you used in the middle of the html at  value =

Comment: i would like to know why the endwhile too

Comment: Please and pretty please

Comment: @brown.cn `<?=` is short for `<?php echo` it's in order to print a php response. Loops and conditions in PHP has two ways of opening closing. One is with brackets `{` and `}` the another is with `:` and `end` i.e. `if (true): .... endif;`

Comment: You sir, deserve my respect. Thank you for being alive.